# Flutter WillPopScope doesn't respond

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get back button of phone to go to specific page using `WillPopScope` but it does not work (won't respond) at all.

`Code`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ArticleArgument;

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
          context,
          '/category',
          arguments: CategoryArgument(
            args.catSlug,
            args.catName,
          ),
        );
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(...)
     );
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: did you try return Future.value(false);

Comment: @SalimBaskoy yes, result was same

Comment: try this  await Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(...);return true;

Comment: Check if the "/category" route is defined. Also, don't return true from onWillPop if you are handling a custom route.

Comment: @SalimBaskoy Thanks, it was require `await` as you've mentioned also somehow required to restart my simulator. Now its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  onWillPop: () async {
        await Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
          context,
          '/category',
          arguments: CategoryArgument(
            args.catSlug,
            args.catName,
          ),
        );
        return true;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, it was require `await` as you've mentioned also somehow required to restart my simulator. Now its working